# Query metrics for multiple instances from AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to fetch CPUUtilization Statistics for multiple instances at once to avoid API rate quota errors.

> &MetricName=CPUUtilization&Namespace=AWS%2FEC2&Statistics.member.1=Sum&Statistics.member.2=SampleCount&Statistics.member.3=Maximum&Statistics.member.4=Minimum&Period=60&StartTime=2015-03-16T18%3A11%3A15&EndTime=2015-03-16T19%3A11%3A15&Dimensions.member.1.Name=InstanceId&Dimensions.member.1.Value=ABC&Dimensions.member.2.Name=InstanceId&Dimensions.member.2.Value=CDE

The response contains data only for CDE instance, and the first value for InstanceId Dimension appears to be ignored.

Does anyone have a solution on how to build a request to query multiple Dimension values in one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following capabilities are currently NOT supported by CloudWatch API:

- Querying multiple instances in the same request
- Querying multiple metrics in the same request