# Get all performance metrics of EC2 instance in one call to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

If I want to get the performance metric, say `CPUUtilization` of an EC2 Instance, I will get this data like this:

```
        GetMetricStatisticsRequest request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest();
        ArrayList<String> stats = new ArrayList<String>();
        stats.add("Average");
        request.setStartTime(startTime);
        request.setEndTime(endTime);
        request.setPeriod(60*6);
        request.setMetricName("CPUUtilization");
        request.setNamespace("AWS/EC2");
        request.setStatistics(stats);
        request.withDimensions(new Dimension().withName("InstanceId").withValue(instanceId));
        GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResult = cloudService.getMetricStatistics(request);
        java.util.List<Datapoint> datapointsList = getMetricStatisticsResult.getDatapoints();
```

AFAIK, `GetMetricStatistics` API returns performance of individual metric only. And if I want to get all the performance metrics like `CPUUtilization, NetworkIn, NetworkOut, DiskReadOps, DiskWriteOps`,etc I'll need to make multiple requests to cloudwatch to get each performance metric one at a time.

Is there any method already out there, using which all the performance metrics can be retrieved in 1 request to cloudwatch?

Comment: The API doesn't support it. 1 request - 1 metric. Similarly, only [one dimension per request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092605/query-metrics-for-multiple-instances-from-aws-cloudwatch/30478878).

Answer (score 1):

Since April 2018, you can retrieve as many as 100 different metrics in a single request, with a total of as many as 100,800 datapoints.

See [GetMetricData API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html)